# how to get the 30 days before date from Todays Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How do you get the 30 days before today in SQL.

Comment: Which SQL DB do you use? MS SQL? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: edit: according to your previous question, it's obviously ms sql.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**T-SQL**

```
declare @thirtydaysago datetime
declare @now datetime
set @now = getdate()
set @thirtydaysago = dateadd(day,-30,@now)

select @now, @thirtydaysago
```

or more simply

```
select dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

([DATEADD on BOL/MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx))

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
```

( [more DATE_ADD examples on ElectricToolbox.com](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/date-add-mysql-intervals-dates/))

Comment: Just realised, this is written in T-Sql (Sql Server), if the answer is needed for MySql then something like: SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) is the equivalent.

Comment: Just add this to your answer:)

Comment: In MySQL, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) works as well

Answer (score 19):

In MS SQL Server, it is:

`SELECT getdate() - 30;`

Comment: What is the difference Gaffi? Why you think edit was necessary?

Comment: I think the only relevant difference in the original and the edited version is that the latter uses the `<code>` tag, which looks better. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT (column name) FROM (table name) WHERE (column name) < DATEADD(Day,-30,GETDATE());
```

**Example.**

```
SELECT `name`, `phone`, `product` FROM `tbmMember` WHERE `dateofServicw` < (Day,-30,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your `where` clause:

```
dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```